# Cannot auto-compile scss files in ruby on rails using sass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sass, stylesheet

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and SO. I have a task to make CSS changes in an existing project built on Ruby on Rails. I searched online and found that `.scss` files auto compile to `.css`. So I started making changes in .scss files. But, when I edit and make changes in the files, it is not getting reflected on the browser. I tried restarting the rails server using command `rails s`, clearing browser cache/cookies, deleted assets folder inside public still, the changes are not getting reflected on the browser.

Finally, I deleted the tmp folder and restarted the rails server. Only then was I able to see my changes on the browser. I want to know if there is an easier way to see the changes directly on saving the scss file?

PS: I have development environment set up and my Gemfile has rails of version '>= 5.0.0.1' and I have sass-rails to '~> 5.0'.

Please let me know if any additional information is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with WSL. we have just shifted ROR project folder outside of 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home' and it worked.